# subtracting the difference of elements in an array

Tags: c

here is the snippet from in question from my code. a is for the array and c represents the counter. 
The code knows when i gained, lost, or stayed the same so it has the right value. Its just that it always displays 0 zero pounds as how much i lost or gained...
is there something wrong with passing the %i in the printf with a[*c]-a[*c-1] ?
I cant think of another way to subtract the difference

```
if(*c > 0){
    if(a[*c] > a[*c-1])
        printf("You gained gained %i pounds!\n",a[*c]-a[*c-1]);
    if(a[*c] < a[*c-1])
        printf( "You lost %i pounds!\n", a[*c-1] - a[*c]);
    if (a[*c] == a[back])
        printf("You're still the same weight as before..\n");
```

Comment: This program is awfully bright and chipper about telling somebody they gained weight.

Comment: Might want to change `"You gained gained %i pounds!\n"` to `"You gained %i pounds!\n"`. No need to double the pain when they're already hearing that they've gained weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integer token in the printf string is `%d`.

So, try this:

```
 printf("You gained gained %d pounds!\n",a[*c]-a[*c-1]);
```

Comment: Thanks that made me realize i initialized the array as a float not an integer, thats why it wasnt working xD